# Не отображается HDD при разметке дисков ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, установка, hdd

Устанавливаю ubuntu 14.04.4 server, доходит до разметки дисков, а HDD не видит вообще. Запускаю LiveCD ubuntu HDD видит. Что я делаю не так?

UPD: Может проблема с разделами HDD?

Comment: Диски как подключены? Напрямую или через RAID-контроллер?

Comment: Через RAID контроллер

Comment: @МАН69К вру, напрямую к материнке подключены. Что я понял: 1) если устанавливать desktop версию Ubuntu, то установка проходит как надо. 2) нужно ли выключить raid через биос и контроллер, и использовать программный предложенный Ubuntu server? 3) raid контроллер не аппаратный получается? Сервер HP ProLiant DL120 G5

Comment: предполагаю, что с live-cd запускается программа linux совсем не той же версии, что и с первого носителя. // *2) нужно ли выключить raid через биос* — лучше отключить. будет меньше проблем в будущем.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо.

Comment: @Vladimir: "нужно ли выключить raid через биос" - да, лучше отключите и создайте программный. И в обслуживании будет проще и в случае (тьфу-тьфу) проблем меньше геморроя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После отключения raid в биосе и в утилите материнки, Ubuntu server увидела диски, после сделал raid массив средствами Ubuntu. Спасибо @MAH69K и @alexander-barakin.